# Jquery does not apply attr autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Very simple question that I don't seem to be able to resolve.

I have this jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready (function () {
    //get top search area working correctly
    var user = jQuery('label[for="user_login"]').first().text ();
    jQuery('label[for="user_login"]').hide();
    jQuery('#user_login').attr('placeholder', user);
    jQuery('.onpage_login .login-username input').attr('placeholder', user);
    jQuery('.onpage_login .login-username input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

    var password = jQuery('label[for="user_pass"]').first().text ();
    jQuery('label[for="user_pass"]').hide();
    jQuery('#user_pass').attr('placeholder', password);
    jQuery('.onpage_login .login-password input').attr('placeholder', password);
    jQuery('.onpage_login .login-password input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    ...
```

For some reason the final line is not actioned, but the placeholder line immediately above is. Looking at the relevant html in Chrome and Firefox element inspectors shows that the placeholder is applied but that the autocomplete is not.

Additionally, no errors are reported by the console.

Does jQuery not respect the autocomplete property?

(Yes I am aware this is a horrible way to implement autocomplete, but I working with closed source software on this occasion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
jQuery('.onpage_login .login-password input').live('focus',function(){
        $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
```

U can also use javascript..

```
document.getElementsById("provideanid")[0].autocomplete="off"  //provide an id to ur password field
```

Here's a fiddle link it works fine..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtFec/)

Comment: Sorry, no joy with that